# Cognito + IDP SAML refreshing token by idp

Tags: office365, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml, idp

I have configured my AWS Cognito with IDP (Office 365) via SAML.
In my application I'm using aws-amplify library in order to sign in user using SSO:
`Auth.federatedSignIn({customProvider :'providerName'})`
I can sign in to my app and almost everything works as expected.
The only one thing that is not clear for me who should refresh id_token IDP or Cognito.
Let's imagine situation:

1. I signed in to my application using SSO (so user exists on IDP side and it's added to my Cognito)
2. IdToken after his expiration timeout has been properly refreshed
3. I disabled user or ever revoked his session on IDP side
4. IdToken after his expiration timeout has been properly refreshed and I can still use my application
5. I disabled user in Cognito
6. IdToken after his expiration timeout has not been refreshed and I'm logged out from my app
   [image]
   I'm curious whether I should be logged out in step 4. I thought that session is refreshed on IDP side which knows that user is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

On step 4, session is revoked which cause a refresh of auth token, as it is no more valid.
The auth token sent (even revoked) and the refresh token are both valid and emitted by Cognito, then the auth token is refreshed normally and user might use the new auth token to use application.

Revoking a session does cause a refresh of the user's token and it is an intended behavior.

Comment: Not sure whether I understood you correctly.
If IDP revoke session then current refresh token should not be valid. Then Cognito should get somehow this information and won't allow to create new id_token. Right? In my opinion Cognito do not make a call to IDP in order to refresh (create new) id_token.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that Cognito does not make any call to IDP before refresh token has expired.
Solution would be to decrease timeout for:
id_token => 60 minutes
refresh_token => 1 day

Another problem I have is that my app has two types of logging (normal using login and password and sso).I should decrease this timeout only for SSO logging. It means that I should use two different Cognito app clients for normal logging and sso logging.
Is it even possible to use two client Ids in one app?

Comment: I figure you're right. This seems either like a giant oversight on AWS's part or a bug. Decreasing token lifetime somehow addresses it, but then you're forcing users to sign-in via SSO again every day. As for using multiple client IDs in one app - that should be possible. For example, if you're using Amplify JS SDK, you can call Amplify.configure with a different client ID right before you initiate the SSO sign-in flow.